# Firebase: How to check if a user auth was overriden by another provider?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Currently, I have four different provider-methods to sign-in/create an account in my app:

- Email and Password
- Google
- Facebook
- Microsoft

When the user logs in the **first time** via one of the providers (or creates an account via email and password) I automatically create a *user-document* with additional info in cloud-firestore. Here comes the problem with one of my providers (email and password):

When the user creates an account with provider "email and password" he can choose whatever email he/she likes and therefore could also use a Google or Microsoft email and provide wrong additional info (wrong name etc.). This wrong information is then  stored in the *user-document* that I create ONCE the user creates his account.

If the above user then not verifies his email and logs in via Google or Microsoft provider, the old "email and password" provider gets overridden BUT NOT THE WRONG  *user-document* I created before.

My question is: Is there a way to observer, or know, that a provider was overridden by another provider and therefore also override the wrong *user-document*?

### General Code

```
// Check if user-document already exists, so it does not get overridden 
// when logging in via Google, Microsoft or Facebook-auth
private suspend fun isUserRegistered(): Boolean {
    val document = dbFirestore.collection(FIREBASE_USER_BASE_PATH).document(dbAuth.currentUser!!.uid).get().await()
    return document.exists()
}

private suspend fun createUserIfNotExist(user: UserNetworkEntity) {
    if (isUserRegistered()) return
    createUserAccount(dbAuth.currentUser!!.uid, user)
}

// Function to check whether user is verified and delete old doc if not verified 
// Here the user-data and the created user-doc will be verified via firebase-admin-sdk
private suspend fun callUserOnCheck(email: String): HttpsCallableResult? {
    return dbFunctions
        .getHttpsCallable(FUNCTION_USER_ON_CHECK_EMAIL)
        .call(hashMapOf<String, String?>("email" to email))
        .await()
}
```

### Code for Google

```
override fun signInWithGoogle(account: GoogleSignInAccount): Flow<LoginStateEvent> = flow {
    val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.idToken, null)

    // Delete old doc if not verified. Getting email from GoogleSignInAccount
    // IMPORTANT: We have to check the old document here, before calling dbAuth.signInWithCredential()
    // because #signInWithCredential() would override the old email-provider
    val email = account.email!!
    callUserOnCheck(email)

    dbAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).await()

    createUserIfNotExist(UserNetworkEntity(fullName = fullName))
}
```

### Code for Facebook

```
override fun signInWithFacebook(): Flow<LoginStateEvent> = flow {
    val result = fLoginManager.registerMCallback(callbackManager)

    val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(result.accessToken.token)

    // Delete old doc if not verified. Getting email from Facebook-GraphResponse
    // IMPORTANT: We have to check the old document here, before calling dbAuth.signInWithCredential()
    // because #signInWithCredential() would override the old email-provider
    callUserOnCheckFacebook(result.accessToken)

    dbAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).await()

    createUserIfNotExist(UserNetworkEntity(fullName = dbAuth.currentUser!!.displayName!!))
}

// Function to check whether user is verified. Special case: Get Facebook email via GraphResponce 
private suspend fun callUserOnCheckFacebook(accessToken: AccessToken) {
    val email = getFacebookEmail(accessToken)
    if (email != null) callUserOnCheck(email)
}

// Get Facebook email via GraphResponce without the need to login via #signInWithCredential()
private suspend fun getFacebookEmail(accessToken: AccessToken) = suspendCancellableCoroutine<String?> { cont ->
    val callback = GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback { json, response ->
        // OnError
        response?.error?.let { cont.resumeWithException(Throwable(it.errorMessage)) }

        // OnSucess
        cont.resume(json?.optString("email"), cont::resumeWithException)
    }

    GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, callback)
}
```

### Code for Microsoft (how to resolve TODO?)

```
override fun signInWithMicrosoft(activity: Activity): Flow<LoginStateEvent> = flow {

   // TODO: Check whether old created user-doc is valid or not before calling
   // dbAuth.pendingAuthResult or ..startActivityForSignIn... as this would
   // override the old existing email-provider.
   // Question: How to get microsoft-email without calling #pendingAuthResult or #startActivityForSignIn ?
    
    val result = dbAuth.pendingAuthResult?.await() ?: dbAuth.startActivityForSignInWithProvider(
        activity,
        microsoftOAuth.build()
    ).await()

    createUserIfNotExist(UserNetworkEntity(fullName = result.user!!.displayName!!))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be looking for the [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)). You can pass this the email of the user, and then check if the email is already in use with the email+password provider (in which case you need to clean up that document).

Comment: Yeah, this might work. But I need to furthermore check, whether the user of the given email is verified or not (in case the user is verified, I don't want to clean up the document). How can I achieve that in combination with above given function `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`?

Comment: There is no way to retrieve a user profile that you don't have credentials for in the client-side SDKs, as that would be a security risk. If you need this kind of check, you'll typically want to perform it in a trusted environment (like your development machine, a server you control, or cloud functions) using the Admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin

Comment: Okay, then I will use the firebase admin sdk for this and write a firebase function for that. Do you know If I can use `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` for all the above given providers? I know how to get the email for email-and-password, google and facebook but not for microsoft.

Comment: In the Admin SDK you'd use `getUserByEmail`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#getuserbyemail

Comment: Yes, I know this, but how can I retrieve the email of the user before he logs in and therefore overrides. I've extended my code example

Comment: *before he logs-in via Microsoft-Auth. See my TODO